# Does splitting a model across multiple GPUs (using model parallelism) reduce model accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

When training a model in PyTorch on multiple GPUs, it should ideally give the same results as using just one GPU. However, are there any specific things to be careful about during implementation?